# How to calculate the centroid of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, algebra

I have the following 5x5 Matrix A:

```
1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 
1 0 1 0 1 
0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 1
```

I am trying to find the centroid in MATLAB so I can find the scatter matrix with:

```
Scatter = A*Centroid*A'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you by centroid mean the "center of mass" for the matrix, you need to account for the placement each '1' has in your matrix. I have done this below by using the meshgrid function:

```
M =[    1 0 0 0 0; 
        1 1 1 0 0; 
        1 0 1 0 1; 
        0 0 1 1 1; 
        0 0 0 0 1];

[rows cols] = size(M);

y = 1:rows;
x = 1:cols;

[X Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

cY = mean(Y(M==1))
cX = mean(X(M==1))
```

Produces cX=3 and cY=3;

For

```
M = [1 0 0;
     0 0 0;
     0 0 1];
```

the result is cX=2;cY=2, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The centroid is simply the mean average computed separately for each dimension.

To find the centroid of each of the rows of your matrix `A`, you can call the [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html) function:

```
centroid = mean(A);
```

The above call to `mean` operates on rows by default.  If you want to get the centroid of the columns of `A`, then you need to call `mean` as follows:

```
centroid = mean(A, 2);
```